# reCaptcha checkbox spins for 15 seconds, then remains unchecked

Tags: recaptcha

I have put reCaptcha on a website. reCaptcha loads without problem but as soon as you click the checkbox, it spins for 15 seconds and remains unchecked. It also does not make any background connection (POST) to google to evaluate the click (should happen).

[image: reCaptcha spinning without success]

I have added this to the header of the website and this is the first script that is loaded.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

I also added this field to my login form:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcGv3MUAAAAALdBp38mExUgAAAAAAH_IX522Gr" style="transform:scale(0.75);transform-origin:100% 0;"></div>
```

There is no network activity (in the network tab of developer tools) when I click the checkbox and the only thing I see in the console tab are 2 strange errors from reCaptcha:

[image: Developer tools console]

I put a bare html form with above modifications on the same domain and server and the reCaptcha works. So I guess this is some kind of conflict with my large existing code (both html and javascript). How can I find or solve the conflict?

Comment: I suggest looking at your **network** tab in your developers tools, as well as the **console** tab to see what the traffic is doing, and what exactly Google's response is.  You can echo Google's response on the server side, and view it in the **network** tab.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It appears that it does not make any network call   in the click evaluation stage (it will however check the captcha string with the ooogle at the server side after submission of the form)

Comment: I’m seeing this too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @davidm_uk: It was an incompatible code in my javascript. Debug revealed it... But even after that this type of captcha proved totally unreliable. It would stop 30% of my users from singning up... It was an ugly mess. I used a simple image captcha.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this on my site by switching to explicit rendering:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaOnLoad&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

...

```
<div id="recaptcha"></div>
```

I use `recaptchaOnLoad` to reset a global `recaptcha_rendered` variable, because my recaptcha is on the second page of a [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) wizard, which I think is what was confusing automatic rendering. I probably don't need this function (also referenced in the `script` tag used to load the recaptcha API above), but it doesn't do any harm:

```
function recaptchaOnLoad() {
    recaptcha_rendered = false;
}
```

When the wizard switches to the page containing the recaptcha, I reset or render it with:

```
if( recaptcha_rendered ) {
    grecaptcha.reset();
} else {
    grecaptcha.render( 'recaptcha', {
        'sitekey': 'my-site-key',
        'callback': 'recaptchaOnData',
        'expired-callback': 'recaptchaOnExpiry'
    } );
    recaptcha_rendered = true;
}
```

It now works every time.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, an infinite spinning loader.
Apparently, a JS library was causing this.
https://mootools.net/

Comment: For me too. I eventually found that it is a script conflict

Answer (score 0):

In my case also this was due to mootools. removing mootools is not a option. so, any work around will be helpful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).